# DocuSign Dynamics CrmWorkflow automate half of the process allowing the user to complete it manually

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, docusignapi

how can I create a workflow in Dynamics CRM Online that creates the envelope, add the recipients and then show the DocuSign web resource so the user can choose the document to use in the envelope and apply any available templates, and then click send?

I am sure it will need to be a custom workflow, not 100% sure how to show the DocuSign frame after the envelope creation. Can I use the existing web resource available after the DS solution installation, or would I need to create my own?

Answer (score 0):

See the DocuSign for Microsoft Dynamics guide [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ds-for-dynamics-online)

See DocuSign Custom Activities on page 21.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have tried this, but I do not want the envelope to be sent, I want it to be created and then show the user the DocuSign wizard page to complete the process. So I will create the envelope, add 2 recipients from the record in Dynamics CRM and then show the user the wizard so they can select what template they want to apply, and the user will be responsible to send the envelope or discard it. Make sense? Is this even possible?